# PowerCenter REG_EXTRACT issue

Tags: regex, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm having an issue, converting REGEXP_SUBSTR from ORACLE to REG_EXTRACT in PWC (9.5.1).

In Oracle i have the statement below:

```
select 
regexp_substr('AA          12345678               *             123','[^' || CHR (9) || ']+', 1,1)  FIELD1,
regexp_substr('AA          12345678               *             123','[^' || CHR (9) || ']+', 1,2)  FIELD2,
regexp_substr('AA          12345678               *             123','[^' || CHR (9) || ']+', 1,3)  FIELD3,
regexp_substr('AA          12345678               *             123','[^' || CHR (9) || ']+', 1,4)  FIELD4
from    DUAL;
```

Result:

```
FIELD1=AA
FIELD2=12345678
FIELD3=*
FIELD4=123
```

In PWC i've created a transformation with 4 ports with a similar regular expression:

```
FIELD1=REG_EXTRACT('AA          12345678               *             123','([^\s]+)', 1,1)
FIELD2=REG_EXTRACT('AA          12345678               *             123','([^\s]+)', 1,2)
FIELD3=REG_EXTRACT('AA          12345678               *             123','([^\s]+)', 1,3)
FIELD4=REG_EXTRACT('AA          12345678               *             123','([^\s]+)', 1,4)
```

Result:

```
FIELD1=NULL
FIELD2=NULL
FIELD3=NULL
FIELD4=NULL
```

Why i'm getting NULL values in FIELD[1-4] ? Can anyone help me with this question ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd and 4th arguments of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `REG_EXTRACT` are different - Oracle's `position` (3rd argument) is PowerCenter's `match_from_start` (4th parameter), `occurrence` and `subPatternNum` are switched similarly.

Try to use the following expressions:

```
FIELD1=REG_EXTRACT('AA  12345678  *  123', '([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)', 1)
FIELD2=REG_EXTRACT('AA  12345678  *  123', '([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)', 2)
FIELD3=REG_EXTRACT('AA  12345678  *  123', '([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)', 3)
FIELD4=REG_EXTRACT('AA  12345678  *  123', '([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)', 4)
```

Here's a list of `REG_EXTRACT` arguments:

1. `subject` - value you want to compare against the regular expression pattern
2. `pattern` - regular expression pattern that you want to match; enclose each subpattern in parentheses
3. `subPatternNum` - subpattern number of the regular expression you want to match
4. `match_from_start` - returns the substring if a match is found from the start of the string; use the following guidelines to determine the match from start value:

   - 0 - matches pattern with subject string from the starting index or any index
   - non-zero - matches pattern with subject string from the starting index

Comment: Shouldn't you match the text inbetween groups like `REG_EXTRACT('AA 12345678 * 123','([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)',4)`?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz and Samik thank you for your help :)

Your solution can solve this problem. However, if i have a dynamic string, sometimes with 4 or more fields how i should define my regular expression ?

Comment: @RuiCaeiro You can ignore any extra fields with a `.*` at the end of the regex.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz yes, i've a maximum number of fields, but i don't have the same fields every time. I will define N ports, according the number of fields.

Comment: @RuiCaeiro You need to use a regex with N subpatterns. How can the fields differ?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz as example:

When i have: 'AA  12345678  *  123' i will create 4 ports, when i have 'AA  12345678  *  123  888 YYY MM' i will create 7 ports.

How i can define one regex without repeat N times the regex "([^\s]+)\s+" ?

Comment: @RuiCaeiro My knowledge of regular expressions does not go that far - read about _repeated subpatterns_ or post a new question about the expression you need.