# Remove character from dynamic string

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, informatica, informatica-powerexchange

I have a file with some junk values and i need to get rid of them while loading that file into a table.
Giving here some example. File is semicolon separated, and last column has those junk values.

```
2019-02-20;05377378;ABC+xY+++Rohit Anita Chicago
2019-02-20;05201343;ABC+xY++Gustav Russia
2019-02-20;07348738;ABC+xy+++Jain Ram Ambarnath
```

Now the last column I have to load without **ABC+xY+++**  value.
but some row i have ABC+xY+++ and some ABC+xY++. any suggestion to get rid of this. which means 2 times or 3 times **+** is available

I am using informatica powercenter for loading this file.
in expression i need to create some substr/instr function. which i can put test here in oracle sql as well to understand quickly if the value coming is properly.

[image]

and my expected output is

[image]

Any suggestion please.

Thanks,
Bithun

Comment: I'm unclear if you're really looking for an Oracle query that hides everything up to the last + from your data already split into multiple columns; an update statement that removes everything after the last +; or some way for Informatica to not load the characters up to the last + in the first place. Also, please post formatted text, not images.

Comment: So do you just want to start with the first character after the last + in the final column, regardless of how many + signs there are?

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for reply. i need some oracle sql statement with substr and instr where i will get the expected output like i posted. either substr-instr which i can use in informatica expression as well. original text i posted in code format. just output i added as image. sql i am changing to coded format also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand your question, but this would do what I think you're asking, would work in SQL and in an Infa expression as well.

```
with myrecs as
(select '2019-02-20;870789789707;ABC+xY++Gustav Russia' as myfield from dual union 
all
 select '2019-02-20;870789789707;ABC+xY+++Carroll Iowa' as myfield from dual)

 select myfield,

    substr(myfield,1, instr(myfield,';',-1)) ---will select everything up to, and including the final semicolon
    ||--concatenate
    substr(myfield,instr(myfield,'+',-1)+1) as yourfield --will select everything after the final plus sign
 from myrecs;

OUTPUT:
myfield                                         yourfield
2019-02-20;870789789707;ABC+xY++Gustav Russia   2019-02-20;870789789707;Gustav Russia
2019-02-20;870789789707;ABC+xY+++Carroll Iowa   2019-02-20;870789789707;Carroll Iowa
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for the following:

```
WITH dat AS (SELECT '2019-02-20;05373487378;ABC+xY++Rohit Anita Chicago' AS adress FROM dual)
SELECT regexp_REPLACE(adress, '(.*);ABC\+x[yY]\+{2,3}(.*)','\1;\2') FROM dat
```

Comment: Do Informatica expressions support regex? They may, I have no idea, just asking ...

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution.

```
substr
    ( 
        Address,
        0, 
        instr(Address ,';',-1)
    )
    ||
substr
    (
        Address,
        instr(Address ,'+',-1)
    )
```

you may want to add +1 in substr start / end position depending on the needs.

Answer (score 0):

Informatica PowerCenter provides a handful of functions to work with regular expression. In this case you'll need REG_EXTRACT.

There's a nice description of the function [already available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28764335/2834065) - check and upvote :)

According to it you'll most likely need to define a port like:

```
your_output_port=REG_EXTRACT(ADDRESS, '([^\+]+)$', 1)
```

[Here's](https://regex101.com/r/bo3L50/2) how I've tested it.